# How to fire Image Button click event in infragistics webdatagrid in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I am using Infragistics (v. 12.2) WebDataGrid in which I have TemplateFieldColumn with Image button.

I want to capture the click event of this Image button.  How to achieve that?

I have below code sample –

```
<asp:Panel  runat=”server”>
   <ig:WebDataGrid ID=”sampleWebGrid”  runat=”server”  AutoGenerateColumns=”False” Width=”100%”>
      <Columns>
         <ig:TemplateDataField  Key=”keyBtnApply”  Header-Text=”update”>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID=”btnUpdate”  runat=”server” CommandName=”U” Width=”30px”  Height=”30px” CommandArgument=”args” ImageUrl=”~/Images/Blue-Button-Icon.png”>
         </ItemTemplate>
         < /ig:TemplateDataField>
      </Columns>
   </ig:WebDataGrid>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to the event from the markup like:
    asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" **OnClick="imageBtn_Click"**

or define it in Page_Load event like:

```
    ImageButton imageBtn = (ImageButton)sampleWebGrid.Rows[0].Items[0].FindControl("btnUpdate");
    imageBtn.Click += imageBtn_Click;

    void imageBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```

However you need to loop though all rows to find the control on the given row if you go with this approach